# How to play a particular portion of an audio file in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I am playing an audio file named 'myTrack.mp3' with SimpleAudioEngine as:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playBackgroundMusic:@"myTrack.mp3" loop:NO];
```

The audio if of the length of **00:17 seconds**, and my plays the whole file. But now I need to play only the portion between time **00:08** and **00:14**. Is it is possible in Cocos2d?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SimpleAudioEngine but with the standard AVQueuePlayer you can do:

1) seekToTime. e.g. (`[_player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(8.0, 1.0)]`)

2) then add time observer to the player:

```
 _timeObserver = [_player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1.0)
                                                  queue:NULL
                                             usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                                 check current duration and stop the playback. 
                                             }];
```

Comment: And if I remember correctly CocosDenshion uses AVAudioPlayer behind the scenes for (background) music playback. Don't think it's accessible through the simple interface, must be in CDAudioManager or similar.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the 'timeObserver' object type? And while adding those lines, I am getting Mach-O linker error: 'Undefined symbols for architecture i386:'. Can u help me pls?

Comment: id timeObserver. finally you can do [_player removeTimeObserver:_timeObserver] and set it to nil. strange issue with i386. what symbols?